# Calculations for responsive divs not working

Tags: css, html

I have a 960px wide wrap, and then a 930px wide main-content wrap with 15px left/right margins. within the main-content wrap there are three divs floated left that are each 280px wide, with 15px margin-right to fill the main-content. To avoid giving the div to the right a margin and make it not fit I gave it another class and set its margin-right to 0.

I am trying to make the site responsive and these are my percentage calculations:
wrap=100%
main-content=96.875%
main-content margins=1.5625%
divs=30.10752688%
div margins=1.61290323

CSS:

```
#page-wrap {
    width:960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: white;
}
#main-content {
    width:96.875%;
    margin:15px 1.5625% 0 1.5625%;
}
.box { (the divs)
    float:left;
    width:30.10752688%;
    min-height:160px;
    margin:30px 1.61290323% 0 0;
}
.right{ (only the div to the right)
    margin-right:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<div id="main-content">  

<div class="box">   
content
</div>

<div class="box">   
content
</div>

<div class="box right"> 
content
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

I don't know why the divs dont seem to resize correctly. Any help would be much appreciated!
The site can be viewed here for now: http://hl.kylmark.se

Comment: Please post the relevant code to reproduce, thanks

Comment: Get firebug in Firefox and play around with it on the fly.  I tried changing your divs width to 29% and was able to produce better results.

Comment: Why do you need that precise of measurements? I'm pretty sure most browsers will round off at 3-4 decimal places anyway...

Comment: When you say they don't "resize correctly", are you talking about how the third div drops off onto the second row when the window is shrunk?

Comment: @dmikester1 well, yes, and also, when i resize the window and inspect the elements in chrome, the margins arent the same percentage of the container as they were at full width, so my calculations must be off but i cant figure out how. oh and at 29% width the divs dont fill out the main-content, and they still drop down underneath each other when the browser gets too small.

Comment: @DrydenLong havent found any source about RWD that says it's fine to round off, every source says the opposite.

Comment: @kylmark Sorry, I should've been more clear in my comment. The browsers will maintain the percentage decimal points but will round the final output. I see that the answer below linked to an article on the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that there's a fixed 10px padding around all of the blue boxes. Since the padding is *added on* to an element's width, it throws off your percentage math.

**Solution 1**

You could just change the side padding on those boxes to a percent value like everything else:

```
.blue {
   ...
   padding: 10px 1.0752688%;
}
```

With that approach you'd be collapsing the borders as you get smaller, which may not be desirable.

**Solution 2**

Maybe a better approach is to change the box-sizing property to calculate width from border to border rather than from content edge to content edge. That way you can have a 10px padding inside a flexible container whose width is figured correctly:

```
.box {
   ...
   width: 32.258065%;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

**One more thing**

You may also want to watch out for is sub-pixel rounding. When your percentages calculate to something other than a whole pixel, the browser has to decide how to round it. If too many things are rounded up, the widths will get too big and cause content jumps like that in some browsers. You'll want to double-check that in your supported browsers. [You can read a good explanation here](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/).

Comment: That did it! I knew I was missing something simple like that! ;)